# Can't setup GitHub Pages

Tags: python, html, github, flask, github-pages

I've created a github repository with my python flask project. But after setting up I only see project readme.md instead of index.html page.

https://github.com/artyaz/QuizGrader

https://artyaz.github.io/QuizGrader/

[GitHub Pages settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noMov.png)

I tried to deleting repository and doing all the process again, but still same.

Answer (score 4):

[GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com) only supports hosting [static websites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_web_page). Your site uses  Flask which does not support generating static sites.